# Why if I change the function Sine to discrete Sine the plot is difference

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, trigonometry

I would like to know why when I change +1 in a discrete Sine change the list line plot and when I plot the function sine anything change.

````
Nmax = 128; (*Number of sites*)

n0 = Nmax/2;(*initial condition*)

\[Psi]inin = Table[Sin[\[Pi] (n0 n)/Nmax], {n, 1, Nmax}];

ListLinePlot[\[Psi]inin]

\[Psi]ini = Table[Sin[\[Pi] (n0 n)/(Nmax + 1)], {n, 1, Nmax}];

ListLinePlot[\[Psi]ini]

Plot[Sin[\[Pi] n0 /Nmax n], {n, 1, Nmax}]

Plot[Sin[\[Pi] (n0 n)/(Nmax + 1)], {n, 1, Nmax}]
```
````

Comment: It looks like aliasing, effectively undersampling the sine wave which will introduce other frequencies in the plot as your sine frequency goes higher. Ever heard of a Moiré pattern? That's likely what's happening here. It's easier to see if you do this: `Nmax = 128;
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[Table[Sin[2 Pi f n ], {n, 1, Nmax}]]
 , {f, 0.1, 4}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the different discrete values is that you're using the same sample rate (Nmax) to sample two sine functions with different frequencies. The first sine function has `frequency = n0/(2 Nmax) = .25`. The second sine function has a lower `frequency = n0/(2(Nmax+1)) = 0.248062`.

Let's show the difference in the sine waves by plotting a few periods of each function - the first function in blue, and the second in red. Compute the frequencies and periods, then draw a graph of both functions on the same graph. It's difficult to see the difference in your graphs because the plots include many periods of the functions and their frequencies are nearly the same.

```
Nmax = 128;(*number of samples*)
n0 = Nmax/2;
N@{f1 = n0/(2 Nmax), p1 = 1/f1}
N@{f2 = n0/(2 (Nmax + 1)), p2 = 1/f2}
Show[ 
 Plot[Sin[2 \[Pi] f1 t], {t, 0, 5 p1}, PlotStyle -> Blue], 
 Plot[Sin[2 \[Pi] f2 t], {t, 0, 5 p2}, PlotStyle -> Red]
]
```

[image: sine functions with different frequencies]

When you sample the first sine function, the sample rate selects the crest and zero of each period. Let's plot the sine function and the discrete samples (red dots) on the same graph.

```
\[Psi]inin = Table[Sin[\[Pi] (n0 n)/Nmax], {n, 1, Nmax}];
Show[
 ListLinePlot[\[Psi]inin, Joined -> False, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Plot[Sin[\[Pi] n0 /Nmax n], {n, 1, Nmax}]]
```

[image: discrete samples of first sine function]

When you sample the second sine function *with the same sample rate*, the samples happen between the crests and zeros. Again, let's plot the sine function and the samples on the same graph. See how the samples don't match the frequency? This demonstrates why the second discrete sine looks different from the first one.

```
\[Psi]ini = Table[Sin[\[Pi] (n0 n)/(Nmax + 1)], {n, 1, Nmax}];
Show[
 ListLinePlot[\[Psi]ini, Joined -> False, PlotStyle -> Red],
 Plot[Sin[\[Pi] (n0 n)/(Nmax + 1)], {n, 1, Nmax}]]
```

[image: discrete samples of second sine function]

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the sample rate in the second discrete sine. There is a form to change the sample rate with the same points and take the crests an zeros like the other discrete sine?

Comment: @MiguelZarate Use [Subdivide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subdivide.html) with `Table[Sin[π (n0 n)/(Nmax + 1)], {n, Most@Subdivide[(2(Nmax + 1)/n0)/4,(Nmax + 1)((2(Nmax + 1)/n0)/4), Nmax]}]` to sample at the crests and zeros.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was very helpful your answer